# Number theory problem on divisors!

Tags: number-theory

> For any positive integer $n$, let $d(n)$ denote the number of positive divisors of $n$ (including $1$ and itself). Determine all positive integers $k$ such that $$\frac{d\left(n^2\right)}{d(n)} = k$$ for some $n$.

Please help me solve this number theory problem. I have tried a lot and found two values of k, $1$ and $3$, but I don't know if there are some others.

Comment: Note that every divisor of $n$ is also a divisor of $n^2$.  Apart from $n^2$ itself, does $n^2$ have any other divisors that $n$ doesn't have?

Comment: Yes, of course! if n is not a prime.

Comment: Which $n$ gets you $3$?

Comment: When n=(p1)^2 ×(p2)^4 , where p1 and p2 are prime

Comment: Yep, just found that.  Thanks.

Comment: Also numbers of the form $p^4\cdot q^2\cdot r^2$ work ($p,q,r$ distinct primes), giving a value of $k=5$.

Comment: Note:  you can get any power of $3$.  For instance, taking $n=2^4\times 3^4\times 5^2\times 7^2$ gets you $9$.

Comment: @paw88789  And starting from that expression you can get any power of $5$.  And combining it with the expression for $3$ you can get anything of the form $3^a\times 5^b$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3409889/a-conjecture-about-the-number-of-divisors-of-a-natural-number

Comment: I'm curious about the origin of this problem, can you tell me where does it come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All odd numbers and only them are representable in the form $d(n^2)/d(n)$. But the proof is tricky!

It is clear that no even number is representable as the numerator is always odd.

For $k$ odd we proceed by induction, clearly $1 = d(1^2)/d(1)$ so $1$ is representable. Now suppose that $k>1$ and that all odd integers up to $k-2$ are representable then if $2^a$ is the largest power of $2$ that divides $k+1$, write 
$$ k = 2^at-1 $$
with $t$ odd and $a \ge 1$, then 
$$ (2^a-1)k = 2^{a+1}(2^{a-1}t-\tfrac{t+1}2)+1 = 2^{a+1}b+1$$
whith $b = 2^{a-1}t-\tfrac{t+1}2$. Now we see that $2b+1 = (2^a-1)t$ and so:
$$ \frac{2^{a+1}b+1}{2^ab+1}\cdot \frac{2^{a}b+1}{2^{a-1}b+1}\cdot \dots \cdot \frac{2^2b + 1}{2b+1} = \frac{(2^a-1)k}{(2^a-1)t} = \frac{k}{t}$$
As $t < k$ is odd, using the induction hypothesis we can find $m$ such that 
$$ t = \frac{d(m^2)}{d(m)} $$
But then chosing primes $p,q,\dots,s$ coprime with $m$ we find that

$$ n = p^{2^{a}b}q^{2^{a-1}b}\dots s^{2b} m $$ 
verifies
$$ \frac{d(n^2)}{d(n)} = \frac{d(p^{2^{a+1}b}q^{2^{a}b}\dots s^{2^2 b})}{d(p^{2^{a}b}q^{2^{a-1}b}\dots s^{2 b})} \cdot \frac{d(m^2)}{d(m)} = \frac{k}t\cdot t = k$$
and the proof is complete!.

Comment: This answer deserves the green check. It's a pity that the question doesn't attract enough attention.

Comment: @WhatsUp Thank you. There are quite a few interesting questions  arising from this problem, I will try to explore them further, for example it seems that there are only a finite number of integers representable using only $k$ primes. It is not clear why some numbers have so many representations and other so few and so on.

Comment: Since every factor is $\frac{4b+1}{2b+1}$, which lies between $\frac{5}{3}$ and $2$, it is clear that only a finite number of integers are representable with $k$ factors: the upper bound being $2^k$. I haven't looked at the number of representations though.

Answer (score 3):

So I saw the comments talking about $31$ and $47$ and eventually $61$ that cannot be found. And I started assembling a proof that $31$ or $47$ cannot be found.

But in the end I arrived at solutions for these numbers.

Extending the search, I end up with a somehow efficient algorithm for finding the solutions.

Here are solutions to all primes under $1000$.

```
(3, [2, 1])
(5, [2, 1, 1])
(7, [8, 5, 4])
(11, [8, 4, 2, 1])
(13, [8, 5, 4, 3])
(17, [4, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(19, [14, 7, 2, 1, 1])
(23, [40, 6, 3, 2, 2])
(29, [19, 17, 16, 11, 7])
(31, [54, 52, 47, 31, 27])
(37, [14, 9, 7, 2, 1, 1])
(41, [10, 8, 5, 4, 2, 1])
(43, [90031, 33, 3, 2, 2, 2])
(47, [82, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2])
(53, [13, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(59, [162, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(61, [76, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(67, [184, 10, 5, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(71, [2112, 8, 5, 3, 3, 1, 1])
(73, [2281, 12, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1])
(79, [59, 8, 5, 4, 4, 2, 1])
(83, [62, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(89, [22, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(97, [121, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(101, [25, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(103, [283, 5, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(107, [5002, 17, 16, 8, 7, 6, 5])
(109, [27, 8, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(113, [28, 14, 7, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(127, [1111, 14, 7, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(131, [2456, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1])
(137, [445, 8, 6, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1])
(139, [382, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1])
(149, [37, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(151, [51151, 526, 406, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
(157, [2551, 8, 6, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2])
(163, [122, 12, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(167, [292, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(173, [43, 7, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(179, [134, 67, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(181, [45, 12, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(191, [143, 12, 10, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(193, [1041862, 8984, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4])
(197, [49, 8, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(199, [348, 10, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(211, [3323, 17, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(223, [204212, 240, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(227, [15606, 19, 17, 16, 16, 12, 12, 11])
(229, [3034, 26, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(233, [78812, 24, 20, 19, 19, 16, 16, 16])
(239, [5437, 7, 6, 6, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(241, [475312, 11, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1])
(251, [86281, 148, 121, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1])
(257, [39062, 321, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(263, [177196, 58, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1])
(269, [67, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(271, [2281, 474, 12, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1])
(277, [2562, 92, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(281, [3442, 6, 6, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2])
(283, [212, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(293, [12379, 229, 6, 6, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2])
(307, [10361, 40, 13, 6, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2])
(311, [544, 8, 8, 6, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2])
(313, [391, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(317, [79, 13, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(331, [1572, 9, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(337, [84, 12, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(347, [607, 6, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(349, [87, 8, 8, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3])
(353, [1147, 6, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(359, [279571, 44, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(367, [25231, 22, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(373, [93, 8, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(379, [51070, 24, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(383, [38587, 30, 15, 8, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4])
(389, [97, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(397, [1687, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(401, [18947, 13, 8, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(409, [10327, 656, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(419, [144031, 364, 170, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(421, [526, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(431, [1616, 76, 13, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(433, [5737, 26, 6, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(439, [2524, 11, 8, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(443, [97792, 97571, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(449, [112, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(457, [1028, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(461, [1037, 62, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(463, [6366, 722, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(467, [4531, 2218, 13, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1])
(479, [262372, 156, 40, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1])
(487, [33481, 25, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1])
(491, [30319, 256, 7, 6, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1])
(499, [198976, 101, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1])
(503, [4904, 144, 6, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1])
(509, [127, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(521, [130, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(523, [14011562, 862, 17, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(541, [25562, 102, 10, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(547, [597187, 992, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(557, [2112, 1810, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(563, [422, 12, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(569, [142, 14, 7, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(571, [1570, 87, 5, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(577, [144, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(587, [2788, 943, 9, 6, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2])
(593, [148, 8, 8, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2])
(599, [1048, 58, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(601, [30200, 33, 8, 6, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2])
(607, [1062, 6, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(613, [5057, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(617, [615920, 1822, 6, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2])
(619, [144072, 85, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(631, [1735, 22, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(641, [722, 160, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(643, [3697, 11, 7, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(647, [728, 485, 364, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(653, [13876, 8, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(659, [1812, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(661, [1487, 8, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(673, [841, 8, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(677, [107812, 17, 8, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3])
(683, [1878, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(691, [47506, 17, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(701, [175, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(709, [13648, 84, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(719, [1977, 367, 8, 8, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4])
(727, [2726, 14, 10, 8, 8, 7, 5, 5, 4, 4])
(733, [4581, 12, 8, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(739, [10900, 3687, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(743, [1300, 6, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(751, [2065, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(757, [23656, 2065, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(761, [2473, 121, 6, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(769, [192, 8, 8, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
(773, [118462, 306, 6, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(787, [221737, 2281, 11, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(797, [4981, 10, 8, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(809, [65731, 16906, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1])
(811, [15206, 9392, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(821, [10057, 37, 6, 6, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(823, [12962, 76, 6, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(827, [2281, 620, 12, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(829, [207, 62, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(839, [6502, 263, 6, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(853, [63335, 39062, 49, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(857, [214, 8, 8, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(859, [2362, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(863, [74002, 17, 8, 6, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1])
(877, [90031, 1096, 33, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1])
(881, [220, 12, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(883, [662, 13, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(887, [1552, 40, 6, 6, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1])
(907, [1587, 857, 12, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(911, [13437, 32, 29, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(919, [39287, 112, 47, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(929, [18812, 32, 12, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(937, [4539062, 1076, 62, 20, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(941, [2373437, 147, 47, 47, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(947, [1657, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(953, [238, 13, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(967, [2659, 49, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(971, [728, 364, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(977, [244, 122, 12, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(983, [737, 162, 5, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(991, [6689, 5312, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
(997, [6013156, 21326, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

---

Some explanation on the algorithm:

Since my original aim was to prove that some numbers **cannot** be expressed, I started with the observation that the number of factors is kind of limited, because every factor is somewhat $2 - \epsilon$.

I then rewrite the formula as $$\prod_{i = 1}^k(1 - \frac{1}{4b_i + 2}) = \frac{p}{2^k}.$$

Now the observation is that one of the factors must be at most $\frac{p^{\frac{1}{k}}}{2}$. So there is an upper bound to the smallest $b_i$.

I just go through all possibilities of this smallest $b_i$, and use a recursive call on the remaining $k - 1$ factors.

One key parameter is $k$, the number of factors. I use multithreading on different $k$, and kill all threads once one thread finds a solution.

Using three threads, I find solutions to all primes under $1000$ within a minute or so.

It is worth noting that using only two threads (i.e. only check the optimal number or (optimal number + 1) of factors) one can also find solutions to all primes under $1000$, just taking longer. I guess it would even work with only one thread, but the current algorithm will be too slow for that.

---

You may try my codes by pasting the following into [this website](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) and press "Evaluate".

```
RR = RealField(200)
giveup = False
def Find(x, k, lbd):
    if giveup: return None
    if k == 1:
        n = (1/(1 - x) - 2) / 4
        if n.denominator() == 1:
            return [n]
        else:
            return None
    bd = Integer(floor((1 / (1 - RR(x)^(RR(1) / k)) - 2) / 4))

    for n in range(bd, lbd - 1, -1):
        newx = x / (1 - 1 / (4 * n + 2))
        if newx >= 1: break
        res = Find(newx, k - 1, n)
        if res is None: continue
        res.append(n)
        return res
    return None

import threading, time
TLIMIT = 3
for p in range(3, 1000, 2):
    if is_prime(p):
        k = ceil(log(RR(p))/log(RR(2)))
        res = None
        giveup = False
        def ThreadFunc(x, k, lbd):
            global res
            myRes = Find(x, k, lbd)
            if myRes is not None: res = myRes
            return
        threads = []
        for j in range(TLIMIT):
            newThread = threading.Thread(target = ThreadFunc, args = (p/2**k, k, 1))
            threads.append(newThread)
            newThread.start()
            k += 1
        while True:
            allEnd = True
            for t in threads:
                if t.is_alive():
                    allEnd = False
                    break
            if allEnd: break
            if res is not None: giveup = True
            time.sleep(0.1)
        print(p, res)
```

Comment: Very good.  I guess I will paste the code to a text file here, gradually learn sage with looping and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if the prime decomposition of $n$ is $\prod\limits_{i\in I} p_i^{a_i}$, then we have the fraction $$\prod\limits_{i\in I}\frac{2a_i+1}{a_i+1}$$

Note that in particular, the numerator must always be odd, which implies that so must the denominator for the fraction to be integral. So, $a_i$ must be even for all $i$. This implies that $n$ **must** be a perfect square.

So, if we let $2b_i=a_i$ for every $a_i$, then we get $$\prod\limits_{i\in I}\frac{4b_i+1}{2b_i+1}$$

Next, I want to show that we can express any odd number as one of these fractions. Note clearly that if any odd number can be expressed as one of these fractions, then any power of it can as well (take the same prime decomposition, but repeat it $n$ times with different primes).

So, we simply need to show that this can be done for any odd prime. We can prove this via strong induction. Suppose prime $p$ is of the form $4n+1$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$. Then, we let $b_1=n$, and then we note that the denominator will be of the form $2b_i+1$, which we know that we can express as a result of the product. So, we are done.

The logic for primes of the form $4n+3$ is trickier. To finish later.

Comment: I don't doubt the claim, but I can't spot the argument.  Can you supply it?

Comment: @lulu Sure, will write up in a minute. Need a quick bathroom break lol

Comment: Thanks.  No hurry.

Comment: @lulu running a search based on this. Cannot yet express $31,47,61$

Comment: @WillJagy  That was what I saw as well...why I asked for details on the argument.  I can't come up with a general principle.

Comment: @lulu I thought I had a proof, but I was incorrect. I only have one for $4n+1$.

Comment: @DonThousand  No worries.  It's an interesting problem...I keep thinking I have a general approach, but then it slips away.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure about $p=61.$ With $b_1=15,$ we find $2 b_1 + 1 = 31,$ and we are not sure we can represent $31.$ I don't see induction holding in the way you describe for the $4n+1$

Comment: @WillJagy I have an idea. For any odd number $2b+1$ that is expressible, it's obvious that $4b+1$ is expressible. Perhaps induction to find which ones are possible?

Comment: @DonThousand another user put some solutions below my answer. He also typed in his program as an but later deleted that. In any case I don't recognize the computer language

Answer (score 1):

primes $4w + 3$ do seem more difficult. The smallest primes I don't have yet are $31, 47.$ I also don't yet have $61.$ So, I am running it again, with up to eight nonzero exponents allowed, largest up to $65.$ It is slowwwwww.

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ sort -n mse.txt 
Fri Oct 25 13:58:12 PDT 2019
       1  half exponents :      0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       3  half exponents :      2   1   0   0   0   0   0
       5  half exponents :      2   1   1   0   0   0   0
       7  half exponents :     12   6   3   0   0   0   0
       7  half exponents :     19  16   2   0   0   0   0
       7  half exponents :     19   5   3   0   0   0   0
       7  half exponents :     26  13   2   0   0   0   0
       7  half exponents :     31  12   2   0   0   0   0
       7  half exponents :     40  11   2   0   0   0   0
       7  half exponents :      8   5   4   0   0   0   0
      11  half exponents :     19   3   2   1   0   0   0
      11  half exponents :      8   4   2   1   0   0   0
      13  half exponents :     12   6   3   3   0   0   0
      13  half exponents :     16   8   4   2   0   0   0
      13  half exponents :     19  16   3   2   0   0   0
      13  half exponents :     19   5   3   3   0   0   0
      13  half exponents :     26  13   3   2   0   0   0
      13  half exponents :     31  12   3   2   0   0   0
      13  half exponents :     40  11   3   2   0   0   0
      13  half exponents :     42  32  21   1   0   0   0
      13  half exponents :     42  38  19   1   0   0   0
      13  half exponents :     42   6   4   2   0   0   0
      13  half exponents :     44  29  22   1   0   0   0
      13  half exponents :      8   5   4   3   0   0   0
      17  half exponents :      4   2   2   1   1   0   0
      19  half exponents :     14   7   2   1   1   0   0
      23  half exponents :     17  12   6   3   1   0   0
      23  half exponents :     17   8   5   4   1   0   0
      23  half exponents :     19  17  16   2   1   0   0
      23  half exponents :     19  17   5   3   1   0   0
      23  half exponents :     26  17  13   2   1   0   0
      23  half exponents :     31  17  12   2   1   0   0
      23  half exponents :     40  17  11   2   1   0   0
      23  half exponents :     40  20  10   2   1   0   0
      23  half exponents :     40  31   2   2   2   0   0
      23  half exponents :     40  38   8   2   1   0   0
      23  half exponents :     40   6   3   2   2   0   0
      29  half exponents :     19  17  16  11   7   0   0
      29  half exponents :     20  19  16  10   7   0   0
      29  half exponents :     26  17  13  11   7   0   0
      29  half exponents :     26  20  13  10   7   0   0
      29  half exponents :     31  17  12  11   7   0   0
      29  half exponents :     31  20  12  10   7   0   0
      29  half exponents :     32  21  16   8   7   0   0
      29  half exponents :     36  18  14   9   7   0   0
      29  half exponents :     38  19  16   8   7   0   0
      29  half exponents :     38  26  13   8   7   0   0
      29  half exponents :     38  31  12   8   7   0   0
      29  half exponents :     40  17  11  11   7   0   0
      29  half exponents :     40  20  11  10   7   0   0
      29  half exponents :     40  38  11   8   7   0   0
      29  half exponents :     42  32  21   7   6   0   0
      29  half exponents :     42  38  19   7   6   0   0
      29  half exponents :     44  29  22   7   6   0   0
      29  half exponents :     47  31  14   7   7   0   0
      29  half exponents :      7   2   2   1   1   1   0
      37  half exponents :     14   9   7   2   1   1   0
      41  half exponents :     10   8   5   4   2   1   0
      41  half exponents :     12  10   6   3   2   1   0
      41  half exponents :     17  12  11  10   1   1   0
      41  half exponents :     19  10   5   3   2   1   0
      41  half exponents :     19  16  10   2   2   1   0
      41  half exponents :     20  12  10  10   1   1   0
      41  half exponents :     26  13  10   2   2   1   0
      41  half exponents :     31  12  10   2   2   1   0
      41  half exponents :     38  12  10   8   1   1   0
      41  half exponents :     40  11  10   2   2   1   0
      41  half exponents :     47  14  10   7   1   1   0
      43  half exponents :     32  12   6   3   3   1   0
      43  half exponents :     32  16   8   4   2   1   0
      43  half exponents :     32  19  16   3   2   1   0
      43  half exponents :     32  19   5   3   3   1   0
      43  half exponents :     32  26  13   3   2   1   0
      43  half exponents :     32  31  12   3   2   1   0
      43  half exponents :     32   8   5   4   3   1   0
      43  half exponents :     40  32  11   3   2   1   0
      43  half exponents :     42  32  32  21   1   1   0
      43  half exponents :     42  32   6   4   2   1   0
      43  half exponents :     42  38  32  19   1   1   0
      43  half exponents :     44  32  29  22   1   1   0
      53  half exponents :     13   2   2   2   1   1   1
      53  half exponents :     17  13  11   8   5   4   0
      53  half exponents :     17  13  12  11   6   3   0
      53  half exponents :     19  17  13  11   5   3   0
      53  half exponents :     19  17  16  13  11   2   0
      53  half exponents :     20  13  10   8   5   4   0
      53  half exponents :     20  13  12  10   6   3   0
      53  half exponents :     20  19  13  10   5   3   0
      53  half exponents :     20  19  16  13  10   2   0
      53  half exponents :     26  17  13  13  11   2   0
      53  half exponents :     26  20  13  13  10   2   0
      53  half exponents :     31  17  13  12  11   2   0
      53  half exponents :     31  20  13  12  10   2   0
      53  half exponents :     32  21  13   8   5   3   0
      53  half exponents :     32  21  16  13   8   2   0
      53  half exponents :     36  18  14  13   9   2   0
      53  half exponents :     38  13  12   8   6   3   0
      53  half exponents :     38  13   8   8   5   4   0
      53  half exponents :     38  19  13   8   5   3   0
      53  half exponents :     38  19  16  13   8   2   0
      53  half exponents :     38  26  13  13   8   2   0
      53  half exponents :     38  31  13  12   8   2   0
      53  half exponents :     40  17  13  11  11   2   0
      53  half exponents :     40  20  13  11  10   2   0
      53  half exponents :     40  38  13  11   8   2   0
      53  half exponents :     42  32  21  13   6   2   0
      53  half exponents :     42  38  19  13   6   2   0
      53  half exponents :     44  29  22  13   6   2   0
      53  half exponents :     47  14  13   7   6   3   0
      53  half exponents :     47  31  14  13   7   2   0
      59  half exponents :     44  22  19  17  16  11   0
      59  half exponents :     44  22  20  19  16  10   0
      59  half exponents :     44  22   2   2   1   1   1
      59  half exponents :     44  26  22  17  13  11   0
      59  half exponents :     44  26  22  20  13  10   0
      59  half exponents :     44  31  22  17  12  11   0
      59  half exponents :     44  31  22  20  12  10   0
      59  half exponents :     44  32  22  21  16   8   0
      59  half exponents :     44  36  22  18  14   9   0
      59  half exponents :     44  38  22  19  16   8   0
      59  half exponents :     44  38  26  22  13   8   0
      59  half exponents :     44  38  31  22  12   8   0
      59  half exponents :     44  40  22  17  11  11   0
      59  half exponents :     44  40  22  20  11  10   0
      59  half exponents :     44  40  38  22  11   8   0
      59  half exponents :     44  42  32  22  21   6   0
      59  half exponents :     44  42  38  22  19   6   0
      59  half exponents :     44  44  29  22  22   6   0
      59  half exponents :     47  44  31  22  14   7   0
      67  half exponents :     50  25   4   2   2   1   1
      73  half exponents :     18  14   9   7   2   1   1
      89  half exponents :     22  12   6   6   3   3   2
      89  half exponents :     22  16   8   6   4   2   2
      89  half exponents :     22  17  11   8   5   4   1
      89  half exponents :     22  17  12  11   6   3   1
      89  half exponents :     22  19  16   6   3   2   2
      89  half exponents :     22  19  17  11   5   3   1
      89  half exponents :     22  19  17  16  11   2   1
      89  half exponents :     22  19   6   5   3   3   2
      89  half exponents :     22  20  10   8   5   4   1
      89  half exponents :     22  20  12  10   6   3   1
      89  half exponents :     22  20  19  10   5   3   1
      89  half exponents :     22  20  19  16  10   2   1
      89  half exponents :     22   8   6   5   4   3   2
      89  half exponents :     26  22  13   6   3   2   2
      89  half exponents :     26  22  17  13  11   2   1
      89  half exponents :     26  22  20  13  10   2   1
      89  half exponents :     31  22  12   6   3   2   2
      89  half exponents :     31  22  17  12  11   2   1
      89  half exponents :     31  22  19  16   2   2   2
      89  half exponents :     31  22  19   5   3   2   2
      89  half exponents :     31  22  20  12  10   2   1
      89  half exponents :     31  22   8   5   4   2   2
      89  half exponents :     31  26  22  13   2   2   2
      89  half exponents :     31  31  22  12   2   2   2
      89  half exponents :     32  22  21  16   8   2   1
      89  half exponents :     32  22  21   8   5   3   1
      89  half exponents :     36  22  18  14   9   2   1
      89  half exponents :     38  22  12   8   6   3   1
      89  half exponents :     38  22  19  16   8   2   1
      89  half exponents :     38  22  19   8   5   3   1
      89  half exponents :     38  22   8   8   5   4   1
      89  half exponents :     38  26  22  13   8   2   1
      89  half exponents :     38  31  22  12   8   2   1
      89  half exponents :     40  22  11   6   3   2   2
      89  half exponents :     40  22  17  11  11   2   1
      89  half exponents :     40  22  20  11  10   2   1
      89  half exponents :     40  31  22  11   2   2   2
      89  half exponents :     40  38  22  11   8   2   1
      89  half exponents :     42  22   6   6   4   2   2
      89  half exponents :     42  32  22  21   6   2   1
      89  half exponents :     42  38  22  19   6   2   1
      89  half exponents :     44  29  22  22   6   2   1
      89  half exponents :     47  22  14   7   6   3   1
      89  half exponents :     47  31  22  14   7   2   1
      97  half exponents :     24  12  12   6   6   3   3
      97  half exponents :     24  12   8   6   5   4   3
      97  half exponents :     24  16  12   8   6   4   2
      97  half exponents :     24  19  12   6   5   3   3
      97  half exponents :     24  19  16  12   6   3   2
      97  half exponents :     24  19  16   8   5   4   2
      97  half exponents :     24  19  17  16  12  11   1
      97  half exponents :     24  19  19  16  16   2   2
      97  half exponents :     24  19  19  16   5   3   2
      97  half exponents :     24  19  19   5   5   3   3
      97  half exponents :     24  19   8   5   5   4   3
      97  half exponents :     24  20  19  16  12  10   1
      97  half exponents :     24   8   8   5   5   4   4
      97  half exponents :     26  24  13  12   6   3   2
      97  half exponents :     26  24  13   8   5   4   2
      97  half exponents :     26  24  17  13  12  11   1
      97  half exponents :     26  24  19  13   5   3   2
      97  half exponents :     26  24  19  16  13   2   2
      97  half exponents :     26  24  20  13  12  10   1
      97  half exponents :     26  26  24  13  13   2   2
      97  half exponents :     31  24  12  12   6   3   2
      97  half exponents :     31  24  12   8   5   4   2
      97  half exponents :     31  24  17  12  12  11   1
      97  half exponents :     31  24  19  12   5   3   2
      97  half exponents :     31  24  19  16  12   2   2
      97  half exponents :     31  24  20  12  12  10   1
      97  half exponents :     31  26  24  13  12   2   2
      97  half exponents :     31  31  24  12  12   2   2
      97  half exponents :     32  24  21  16  12   8   1
      97  half exponents :     36  24  18  14  12   9   1
      97  half exponents :     38  24  19  16  12   8   1
      97  half exponents :     38  26  24  13  12   8   1
      97  half exponents :     38  31  24  12  12   8   1
      97  half exponents :     40  24  11   8   5   4   2
      97  half exponents :     40  24  12  11   6   3   2
      97  half exponents :     40  24  17  12  11  11   1
      97  half exponents :     40  24  19  11   5   3   2
      97  half exponents :     40  24  19  16  11   2   2
      97  half exponents :     40  24  20  12  11  10   1
      97  half exponents :     40  26  24  13  11   2   2
      97  half exponents :     40  31  24  12  11   2   2
      97  half exponents :     40  38  24  12  11   8   1
      97  half exponents :     40  40  24  11  11   2   2
      97  half exponents :     42  24  12   6   6   4   2
      97  half exponents :     42  24  19   6   5   4   2
      97  half exponents :     42  32  24  21  12   6   1
      97  half exponents :     42  32  24  21  19   5   1
      97  half exponents :     42  38  24  19  12   6   1
      97  half exponents :     42  38  24  19  19   5   1
      97  half exponents :     44  29  24  22  12   6   1
      97  half exponents :     44  29  24  22  19   5   1
      97  half exponents :     47  24  19  16  14   7   1
      97  half exponents :     47  26  24  14  13   7   1
      97  half exponents :     47  31  24  14  12   7   1
      97  half exponents :     47  40  24  14  11   7   1
      97  half exponents :     50  47  33  25  24   4   1
     101  half exponents :     25  17  11   8   5   4   4
     101  half exponents :     25  17  12  11   6   4   3
     101  half exponents :     25  19  17  11   5   4   3
     101  half exponents :     25  19  17  16  11   4   2
     101  half exponents :     25  20  10   8   5   4   4
     101  half exponents :     25  20  12  10   6   4   3
     101  half exponents :     25  20  19  10   5   4   3
     101  half exponents :     25  20  19  16  10   4   2
     101  half exponents :     26  25  17  13  11   4   2
     101  half exponents :     26  25  20  13  10   4   2
     101  half exponents :     31  25  17  12  11   4   2
     101  half exponents :     31  25  20  12  10   4   2
     101  half exponents :     32  25  21  12   6   3   3
     101  half exponents :     32  25  21  16   8   4   2
     101  half exponents :     32  25  21  19  16   3   2
     101  half exponents :     32  25  21  19   5   3   3
     101  half exponents :     32  25  21   8   5   4   3
     101  half exponents :     32  26  25  21  13   3   2
     101  half exponents :     32  31  25  21  12   3   2
     101  half exponents :     36  25  18  14   9   4   2
     101  half exponents :     38  25  12   8   6   4   3
     101  half exponents :     38  25  19  12   6   3   3
     101  half exponents :     38  25  19  16   8   4   2
     101  half exponents :     38  25  19  19  16   3   2
     101  half exponents :     38  25  19  19   5   3   3
     101  half exponents :     38  25  19   8   5   4   3
     101  half exponents :     38  25   8   8   5   4   4
     101  half exponents :     38  26  25  13   8   4   2
     101  half exponents :     38  26  25  19  13   3   2
     101  half exponents :     38  31  25  12   8   4   2
     101  half exponents :     38  31  25  19  12   3   2
     101  half exponents :     40  25  17  11  11   4   2
     101  half exponents :     40  25  20  11  10   4   2
     101  half exponents :     40  32  25  21  11   3   2
     101  half exponents :     40  38  25  11   8   4   2
     101  half exponents :     40  38  25  19  11   3   2
     101  half exponents :     42  32  25  21   6   4   2
     101  half exponents :     42  32  32  25  21  21   1
     101  half exponents :     42  38  25  19   6   4   2
     101  half exponents :     42  38  32  25  21  19   1
     101  half exponents :     42  38  38  25  19  19   1
     101  half exponents :     44  29  25  22   6   4   2
     101  half exponents :     44  32  29  25  22  21   1
     101  half exponents :     44  38  29  25  22  19   1
     101  half exponents :     47  25  14   7   6   4   3
     101  half exponents :     47  31  25  14   7   4   2
     109  half exponents :     27  19  17  16  11   8   4
     109  half exponents :     27  19  19  17  16  11   3
     109  half exponents :     27  20  19  16  10   8   4
     109  half exponents :     27  20  19  19  16  10   3
     109  half exponents :     27  26  17  13  11   8   4
     109  half exponents :     27  26  19  17  13  11   3
     109  half exponents :     27  26  20  13  10   8   4
     109  half exponents :     27  26  20  19  13  10   3
     109  half exponents :     31  27  17  12  11   8   4
     109  half exponents :     31  27  19  17  12  11   3
     109  half exponents :     31  27  20  12  10   8   4
     109  half exponents :     31  27  20  19  12  10   3
     109  half exponents :     32  27  21  16   8   8   4
     109  half exponents :     32  27  21  19  16   8   3
     109  half exponents :     32  27  26  21  13   8   3
     109  half exponents :     32  31  27  21  12   8   3
     109  half exponents :     36  27  18  14   9   8   4
     109  half exponents :     36  27  19  18  14   9   3
     109  half exponents :     38  27  19  16   8   8   4
     109  half exponents :     38  27  19  19  16   8   3
     109  half exponents :     38  27  26  13   8   8   4
     109  half exponents :     38  27  26  19  13   8   3
     109  half exponents :     38  31  27  12   8   8   4
     109  half exponents :     38  31  27  19  12   8   3
     109  half exponents :     40  27  17  11  11   8   4
     109  half exponents :     40  27  19  17  11  11   3
     109  half exponents :     40  27  20  11  10   8   4
     109  half exponents :     40  27  20  19  11  10   3
     109  half exponents :     40  32  27  21  11   8   3
     109  half exponents :     40  38  27  11   8   8   4
     109  half exponents :     40  38  27  19  11   8   3
     109  half exponents :     42  27  19  17  11   6   4
     109  half exponents :     42  27  20  19  10   6   4
     109  half exponents :     42  32  27  21  19   6   3
     109  half exponents :     42  32  27  21   8   6   4
     109  half exponents :     42  32  31  27  21  19   2
     109  half exponents :     42  38  27  19  19   6   3
     109  half exponents :     42  38  27  19   8   6   4
     109  half exponents :     42  38  31  27  19  19   2
     109  half exponents :     44  29  27  22  19   6   3
     109  half exponents :     44  29  27  22   8   6   4
     109  half exponents :     44  31  29  27  22  19   2
     109  half exponents :     47  31  27  14   8   7   4
     109  half exponents :     47  31  27  19  14   7   3
     113  half exponents :     28  19  17  16  14  11   7
     113  half exponents :     28  20  19  16  14  10   7
     113  half exponents :     28  26  17  14  13  11   7
     113  half exponents :     28  26  20  14  13  10   7
     113  half exponents :     31  28  17  14  12  11   7
     113  half exponents :     31  28  20  14  12  10   7
     113  half exponents :     32  28  21  16  14   8   7
     113  half exponents :     36  28  18  14  14   9   7
     113  half exponents :     38  28  19  16  14   8   7
     113  half exponents :     38  28  26  14  13   8   7
     113  half exponents :     38  31  28  14  12   8   7
     113  half exponents :     40  28  17  14  11  11   7
     113  half exponents :     40  28  20  14  11  10   7
     113  half exponents :     40  38  28  14  11   8   7
     113  half exponents :     42  32  28  21  14   7   6
     113  half exponents :     42  38  28  19  14   7   6
     113  half exponents :     44  29  28  22  14   7   6
     113  half exponents :     47  31  28  14  14   7   7
     113  half exponents :     50  33  28  25  17  11   4
     113  half exponents :     50  33  28  25  20  10   4
     113  half exponents :     50  33  32  28  25  21   3
     113  half exponents :     50  38  33  28  25  19   3
     113  half exponents :     50  38  33  28  25   8   4
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ 
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

Comment: Yea, my proof for $4n+3$ isn't working.

Comment: For $31$: $[54, 52, 47, 31, 27]$; and for $47$: $[82, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2]$.

Comment: And for $61$: $[11762462, 31, 27, 26, 24, 22]$.

Comment: Some other values missing in your output: $71: [2112, 8, 5, 3, 3, 1, 1]$; $79:[59, 8, 5, 4, 4, 2, 1]$;$83:[3631, 3295, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2]$;$103:[85361, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 5]$;$107:[5002, 17, 16, 8, 7, 6, 5]$.

Comment: While it's now plausible that an expression exists for any prime number, I don't know if there's a general argument. Also @lulu if you are interested.

Comment: @WhatsUp very nice. No idea how you did this. Meanwhile, it still appears that your 31: [54,52,47,31,27]   should give us 61: [54,52,47,31,27,15]. Added: I don't recognize the computer language in your deleted answer.

Comment: @WillJagy I posted an answer with my codes. The language is Sage, and you can try it online. I deleted the answer because I was editting it (:

Comment: @WhatsUp thank you. I downloaded SAGE, years ago, but learned only one-line commands.

Comment: @WillJagy Now with sagecell you don't even have to download or install it, quite convenient. I'm working on an explanation of my algorithm.