# A conjecture about the number of divisors of a natural number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, conjectures

Conjecture:

> $\tau(n)\mid\tau(n^2)\iff$  $n$ is a perfect square and $\sqrt n=p^2s$,
>   where $p$ is prime and $s$ is a non prime squarefree number  such that $\gcd(p,s)=1$.

$\tau(n)$ is the number of factors of $n$.
See this question on MSE:
[Number theory problem on divisors!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3408341/number-theory-problem-on-divisors)

It's tested for $n<10,000$.

Comment: It is trivial that $n$ is a square when the divisibility above happens since the number of divisors is odd iff the number is a square and of course divisors of odd numbers are odd

Comment: So $n = p^4s^2$ and $n^2 =p^8s^4$?  That doesn't follow.  $\tau(n)= 5*3^m$ and $\tau(n^2) = 9*5^m$ where $m$ is the number of prime factors of $s$.  That will hold only if $m= 2$.  So for example if $\sqrt n = 2^2*3*5*7$ and $n=2^4*3^2*5^2*7^2$ and $\tau(n)=5*27$ but $\tau(n^2)=9*125$ and $5*27\not \mid 9*125$.  Did you forget to speculate that $s$ must have exactly two prime factors? or is $n=176400>10,000$ that you just didn't test far enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n=p^4s^2$ with $p$ prime, $s$ is a product of $m\ge1$ distinct primes $q_1,\ldots,q_m$ and $p\nmid s$, then
$$\tau(n) =\tau(p^4)\tau(q_1^2)\cdots \tau(q_m^2)=5\cdot 3\cdots 3=5\cdot 3^m$$
and
$$\tau(n^2) =\tau(p^8)\tau(q_1^4)\cdots \tau(q_m^4)=9\cdot 5\cdots 5=3^2\cdot 5^m.$$
It follows that for such $n$, we have $\tau(n)\mid\tau(n^2)$ only if $m\le 2$.
This allows us to find an explicit counterexample:
Let $n=420^2=176400$. 
Then $$\begin{align}\tau(n)&=\tau(2^4\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^2\cdot 7^2)=135\\\tau(n^2)&=\tau(2^8\cdot 3^4\cdot 5^4\cdot 7^4)=1125=8\cdot 135+45.\end{align}$$

---

It is also not hard to find counterexamples to the other direction: 
Let $$n=29674142746122490321305600000000000000000000.$$
Then $$\begin{align}
\tau(n)=\tau(2^{40}3^{24}5^{20}7^211^213^2)&=41\cdot25\cdot 21\cdot 3^3\\
\tau(n^2)=\tau(2^{80}3^{48}5^{40}7^411^413^4)&=81\cdot49\cdot 41\cdot 5^3=35\cdot \tau(n).\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Notice the smallest case where $m > 2$ is $n=176400$ which is much larger than the test cases.....  Considering the number of prime factors even to small powers makes $10, 000$ a much to small sample size.

Comment: I was fooled by the examples $\sqrt n=2\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 5$, $2\cdot 2\cdot 5\cdot 7$, $2\cdot 3\cdot 3 \cdot 5$.

Comment: @fleablood Indeed. I am however not sure whether the counterexample for the toher direction is the smallest one - it was just the one I could stick together with least effort.

Comment: "toher direction".  You mean were $\tau(n)|\tau(n^2)$ but not nesc $\sqrt n= p^2s$...?  No, I haven't tested that far either.  But smallest $p^2s$ counterexample would need $s$ haveing at least $3$ prime factors and so $n$ having at least four.  Then smallest $p^4r^2q^2t^2$ is $2^4*3^2*5^2*7^2$ so that is the smallest counterexample in that direction.